# Using math functions in a tikzmath coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath, tikzmath

I am trying to execute the following code where I compute the coordinates using the TikZ `math` library and then I draw them in TikZ.

Why does it output error `! Package pgf Error: No shape named '2*cos(60' is known.` when defining the coordinate with mathematical functions (in my case with `sin` and `cos`)?
The pgf math functions should be readily available in the TikZ math library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{
coordinate \x;
\x1=(0,0);
\x2=(1.5,0);
\x3 = (2*cos(60), 2*sin(60));
}

\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (2.2,0) node [anchor=west] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,2.2) node [anchor=south] {$y$};
\draw [red,thick] (\x1) -- (\x2) -- (\x3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Expected drawing

[image]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585586/38080

Comment: @Rmano, thanks! your link explains exactly the reason for the brackets: the parser looks for the end parenthesis `)` of the coordinate and the parenthesis of the function interfere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just missed (if someone could explain why...) some **curly brackets** around the math operations in the coordinates.

Such brackets are not needed when using a normal variable, e.g., `\a= 2*cos(60)`, but seemingly are needed for coordinates definitions. For example, `\a=2*cos(60); \b=2*sin(60); \x3=(\a,\b);` in the `\tikzmath` environment would work, but it is too verbose.

Easiest solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzmath{
coordinate \x;
\x1=(0,0);
\x2=(1.5,0);
\x3 = ({2*cos(60)}, {2*sin(60)});
}

\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2,2);
\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (2.2,0) node [anchor=west] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,2.2) node [anchor=south] {$y$};
\draw [red,thick] (\x1) -- (\x2) -- (\x3) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```